# Finding count of specific span tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

My code is

```
final_id = "PlayerID_SCDG" + str(0)
find_id = beautiful_soup_parsing.find("span", id = final_id)
final_id = find_id.text
```

The value of the first of the two final_id variables shown above is a value such as

```
PlayerID:
<span id="PlayerID_SCDG">109275</span>
```

How would I find the count of unique Player IDs on a page?

Comment: Is that a single playerId or the count of distinct ids in the html above?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking after.If want to fetch the value `109275` try that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''PlayerID:
<span id="PlayerID_SCDG">109275</span>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.find('span',id='PlayerID_SCDG').text)
```